# Manage Windows File Share Permissions with Local Group

Tags: windows, permissions, share, local, groups

Here is my situation: I am a Local Administrator on a plain Windows XP machine. Due to organizational issues, people want to run a Windows file share on this machine.

I thought it might be a nifty idea to add all users (domain users) which should be able to access the share to a local group and give file and share permissions to this group.

Well, somehow this does not work. Adding myself to the group and trying to access the share, I am asked to access the hosting computer (on which I do not have a separate account), and cannot do so using my domain login.

Of course, I could duplicate the list of domain users in both the file and share permissions, but I wanted to avoid this duplication.

Sorry for being an absolute noob, I'm not and admin per se, they have just allowed me to run my Wiki on that machine and now I'm 'admin'.

Thanks for your consideration,

Christian

Comment: When you say domain users, is this just a subset of users, on the domain, who need access? Because there is an AD group called "Domain Users" which is every user on the domain, and could cause some confusion.

Comment: This machine is a member of the domain, right?

Comment: 'Domain Users' means a subset of users, not all users in the domain.

Comment: Yes, the machine is a member of the domain.

Comment: It would be much better to use a domain group for this. Talk to your admin(s) about getting that set up.